# Put orders from specific group on Hold

Tags: orders, magento-community, order-status, customer-group

We have a general group and a wholesale group. Is it possible to automatically put all orders that come from the wholesale customer group on HOLD? We need to approve those purchases before the shipping department processes them and to avoid mistakes we'd like the order to be on hold.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use an observer for this

> /app/etc/modules/Tbi_Orderhook.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tbi_Orderhook>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Tbi_Orderhook>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> /app/code/community/Tbi/Orderhook/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tbi_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Tbi_Orderhook>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <models>           
            <orderhook>
                <class>Tbi_Orderhook_Model</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>

        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <auto_invoice_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>orderhook/observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </auto_invoice_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>

    </global>
</config>
```

Create observer file

> app/code/community/Tbi/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Tbi_Orderhook_Model_Observer
{
    public function implementOrderStatus($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        $customer_group_id = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
         if($customer_group_id == 'yourequiredid'){
                $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function _getPaymentMethod($order)
    {
        return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    }

    private function _processOrderStatus($order)
    {

        $this->_changeOrderStatus($order);
        return true;
    }

    private function _changeOrderStatus($order)
    {
        $statusMessage = '';
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, true);       
    $order->save();
    }
}
```